# Can't send mail using JavaMail due to javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException

Tags: java, email, authentication, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to configure my app to send mail, using gmail. I looked up the gmail javamail documentation and I've been able to write that piece of code:

```
String from = mymail;
String pass = mypass;
String[] to = { somemail }; // list of recipient email addresses
String subject = "Java send mail example";
String body = "Welcome to JavaMail!";

Properties props = System.getProperties();
String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
props.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(from, pass);
    }
});
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

try {
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
    InternetAddress[] toAddress = new InternetAddress[to.length];

    // To get the array of addresses
    for( int i = 0; i < to.length; i++ ) {
        toAddress[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i]);
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < toAddress.length; i++) {
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress[i]);
    }

    message.setSubject(subject);
    message.setText(body);
    Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
    transport.connect(host, from, pass);
    transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
    transport.close();
}
catch (AddressException ae) {
    ae.printStackTrace();
}
catch (MessagingException me) {
    me.printStackTrace();
}
```

but I keep getting the following error:

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.c....
```

What should I try to change ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be that Gmail account is not configured to use less secure authentication. You can change that by logging into the account you are trying to send email from and then going to this [page](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps). On that page you can turn on access by less secure authentication. This should solve the problem